# Why does predict, on a subset of the original data, fail using gls when lm does the trick?

Tags: r, debugging, predict, nlme

The problem is illustrated using the code below. If you run it you will see that lm handles the predict gracefully while gls fails to do so. This is most likely a problem in predict.gls but I don't understand why. This is only an issue when using the factor call. Without it everything works out fine. I am fairly confident that predict.gls fails because all levels are not present in the new dataset. However, lm works it out. To me it feels like a bug but I'm not proficient enough with the gls code to determine it.

```
library(nlme)

# lm example
myfit<-lm(mpg~factor(cyl):disp+hp, data=mtcars)
mypred<-predict(myfit, mtcars[1:3, 1:7])

# gls example
myfit2<-gls(mpg~factor(cyl):disp+hp, data=mtcars)
mypred2<-predict(myfit2, mtcars[1:3, 1:7])
```

It fails with the error:

```
# Error in X[, names(cf), drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any ideas?

My R.version output:

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          0.2
year           2013
month          09
day            25
svn rev        63987
language       R
version.string R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
nickname       Frisbee Sailing

nlme package version: "package ‘nlme’ version 3.1-113"

Comment: I suppose that one could argue that `predict.gls` should use the `xlev` argument in `model.frame`. But the authors might argue that you really should be converting the column to factor up front in your data.

Comment: I believe the error is caused by cyl==8 missing from newdata. `mypred2<-predict(myfit2, mtcars[1:5, 1:7])` works. This might be considered a bug in how `predict.gls` handles factors.

Comment: @joran You get the same error after `mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl); myfit2<-gls(mpg~cyl:disp+hp, data=mtcars)`.

Comment: @Roland If thats the case, then it does seem like an oversight in their use of model.frame

Comment: @RScriv I'm pretty sure that, while you are right in general, that is not the source of this particular error.

Comment: In the code I can see the drop unused levels flag being set to true in the gls case just like in the lm case so that to me suggests that the "missing" values in a factor should pose no problem. Or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: @RScriv You shouldn't look at the usefulness or quality of the model provided. It's just a dummy example to illustrate the issue. :)

Comment: I've encountered this error as well (very much late to the party, but the bug remains unfixed). A quick and dirty workaround is just: rbind a data frame with all possible factor values to the data you're passing as newdata to the predict function, and then remove it again from the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not the author of `predict.gls` I can't answer precisely *why* it was written this way, but I'm hesitant to suggest that this is a bug in a function/package that have been around this long.

Anyway...the reason it works with `lm` is that when `predict.lm` calls `model.frame`:

```
m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, 
            xlev = object$xlevels)
```

it is using the `xlev` argument and the information on the levels from the fitted model object itself. I don't believe that `gls` object stores this information at all.

In `predict.gls` there are two things going on. First, the initial call to `model.frame`:

```
mfArgs <- list(formula = form, data = newdata, na.action = na.action)
mfArgs$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
dataMod <- do.call("model.frame", mfArgs)
```

Note that here we're not using the `xlev` argument, and in fact we're explicitly saying to drop unused levels. If you create your own version of `predict.gls` and comment our the `drop.unused.levels` line, it should work, *as long as you don't call `factor` in your formula!*

Why?

Because later on we see this:

```
X <- model.matrix(form, dataMod)
```

where your formula is being re-applied. Which means that `factor` is being called on columns with levels that don't exist, forcing them to be dropped.

So when I use a version of `predict.gls` that comments out the `drop.unused.levels` line, *and* I set `cyl` to be a factor up front in the data frame, it generates predictions for me just fine.

But I would suggest asking the package authors as to whether this is intended behavior or not. It seems odd to me, but like I said, for a package this old and well used it seems strange that something like this would be un-intended.

Comment: I think this is a bug.  I reported something similar as a bug today: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17228